# how to sync Sequelize model with pre defined table

Tags: sequelize.js

I understand the below code is creating `NEW` table in the data base and call it `User` then add data to it.
I've the table `User` already existing in my data, I just want to do a model to sync with with this table, how can I do it?

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password');

var User = sequelize.define('user', {
    username: Sequelize.STRING,
    birthday: Sequelize.DATE
});

sequelize.sync().then(function() {
   return User.create({
       username: 'janedoe',
       birthday: new Date(1980, 6, 20)
    });
}).then(function(jane) {
       console.log(jane.get({
       plain: true
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks the only option is to wrote `migration`